# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable (python beginner)

Tags: python, floating-point

So I've recently started school,learning software development.  Total noob.
I followed the instructions perfectly yet I keep getting "cant call float.

Here is the code; I also included a screenshot.  Thanks in advance!

```
a = float(input("Enter first number:"))
b = float(input("Enter second number:"))

add = a + b
sub = a - b
mul = a * b
div = a / b
print(sub)
print(add)
print(mul)
print(div)
```

Comment: Python doesn't use `:` to assign a value to a variable, maybe you meant to use `=` instead.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There are a lot of issues in this snippet here, it might be helpful to follow [this tutorial](https://www.learnpython.org/) so you can get some of the basic syntax of python down.

Comment: I tried that as well, it didn't fix it.  Let me try again, perhaps I missed something

Comment: You also seem to have an extraneous equals in `add:a=b` it should probably be `add = a + b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is all wrong. To assign a value to a variable you need to use `=`. Try...

```py
a = float(input('Enter a first number'))
b = float(input('Enter a second number'))
```

Then to define functions you need to use `def`

```py
def add(a,b):
    return a + b

def sub(a,b):
    return a - b

def mul(a,b):
    return a * b

def div(a,b):
    return a / b
```

Then to print the results you have to call the functions with the parameters

```py
print(add(a,b))
# etc.
```

All together, it should look like this in the console

```py
>>> def add(a,b):
...     return a + b
...
>>> def sub(a,b):
...     return a - b
...
>>> def mul(a,b):
...     return a * b
...
>>> def div(a,b):
...     return a / b
...
>>> a = float(input('Enter a first number'))
Enter a first number 5
>>> b = float(input('Enter a second number'))
Enter a second number 4
>>> add(a,b)
9.0
>>> sub(a,b)
1.0
>>> mul(a,b)
20.0
>>> div(a,b)
1.25
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create function such as :

```
def calculate(a, b):
    add = a+b
    sub = a-b
    mul = a*b
    div = a/b
    return add, sub, mul, div
```

then call the fucntion as following :

```
a, b = 1,2
add, sub, mul, div = calculate(a, b)
print('add : {}'.format(add))
print('sub : {}'.format(sub))
print('mul : {}'.format(mul))
print('div : {}'.format(div))
```

it will give you as :

```
add : 3
sub : -1
mul : 2
div : 0.5
```